# Making the header of a group box unique for each instance

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I have created a `Groupbox` resource directory, and created a style that affects the groupbox.

**Here is my `Resource Directory` code:**

```
<Style x:Key="grpNumbers" TargetType="GroupBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupBox">
                <Border
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    BorderBrush="#25A0DA" CornerRadius="10">
                    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Carrier" Foreground="White" Background="#151515" Height="38" 
                          Margin="30,-195,0,0"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The issue is that I want the group box style to not be *coupled* with the `Content` in the `Label`.

**Currently it is getting instantiated in the `mainwindow` like this:**

```
<GroupBox Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=grpNumbers}" Grid.Column="1"  BorderBrush="#272727" Grid.Row="1" Height="200" Margin="20"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Header="Carrier information" Foreground="White" FontSize="20" BorderThickness="0.2">
</GroupBox>
```

But obviously the above groupboxes' `Header` tag isn't overriding the header of my custom groupbox but I need it too, can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify your Style too look like this:

```
<Style x:Key="grpNumbers" TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border BorderThickness="1"
                            BorderBrush="#25A0DA" 
                            CornerRadius="10">
                        <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                               Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                               Foreground="White" 
                               Background="#151515" 
                               Height="38" 
                               Margin="30,-195,0,0"/>
                    </Border>
                    <!-- Responsible for displaying what you put inside of your GroupBox -->
                    <ContentPresenter Margin="5,25,5,5" />                        
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

which can then be used like this:

```
<GroupBox Style="{StaticResource grpNumbers}" 
          Grid.Column="1"
          BorderBrush="#272727" 
          Grid.Row="1" 
          Height="200" 
          Margin="20"  
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          Header="Carrier information" 
          Foreground="White" 
          FontSize="20" 
          BorderThickness="0.2">
    <TextBox /> <!-- or whatever you want inside your GroupBox -->
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: @CHunter I'm still working on it, please give me another minute or two

Comment: I'm actually getting a 'Child is set more than once' issue

Comment: @CHunter my mistake.. please try again now, edited the Style once again.

Comment: @CHunter Good to hear that it helped. Thanks for making this the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Label inside ContentTemplate can use TemplateBinding to bind Header:

```
<Label Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>
```